# setLayoutParams in ArrayAdapter in getView must set params only to one view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, layoutparams

I want the last cell to have for example 300dp height. Here is my getView method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card_list, parent, false);
    }

    if (position == getCount() - 1) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = rowView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = 300;
        rowView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
    return rowView;
}
```

I want the last cell to have 300dp height. It works good, last cell have 300dp height, when I'a scroll to bottom. But when I scroll up, appears, that a lot of other elements of list become 300dp in height.

Comment: That's because the position gives the current position of the element. It's not a static number. The ordering changes continually. Position 1 can be in the dead center of the list while 2 is drawn above 1 and 3 is below 2. You have NO guarantees about the positions and they will change every time you scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have to set an else too. Since views are recycled you will have to restore their height if you're not dealing with `position == getCount() - 1`

It should look like:

```
 if (position == getCount() - 1) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = rowView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = 300;
        rowView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }else{
        viewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = rowView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = ?????; //your other height here.. (WRAP_CONTENT perhaps?)
        rowView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```